# RPi Bullseye: libcamera-jpeg does not write to USB drive, while libcamera-vid does

Tags: pi-3, usb, camera, fstab, libcamera

I'm running a Python script on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+. This script automatically takes video and stills using the Raspberry Pi camera and should write it to an external USB drive. I've mounted a USB drive in the `/etc/fstab` as follows:

`UUID=XXXXXXXXX /home/pi/USBDRIVENAME ntfs defaults,auto,users,rw,nofail,umask=000 0 0`

Taking video, converting it and writing it to the USB drive using the Python script, like this works. I see both the converted and original file:

`libcamera-vid -t 7500 -o /home/pi/USBDRIVENAME/movie.h264`
`MP4Box -add /home/pi/USBDRIVENAME/movie.h264 /home/pi/USBDRIVENAME/movie.mp4`

However, trying to take stills via my Python script using:

`libcamera-jpeg -o /home/pi/USBDRIVENAME/still.jpg`

does **NOT** work. Executing the same line by copy-pasting it in the cmd **does** work: the still appears in the USB drive.

I also tried mounting the usb drive to the root filesystem in */mnt/usb* and writing the video and stills to that location using:

`libcamera-vid -t 7500 -o /mnt/usb/movie.h264`
`MP4Box -add /mnt/usb/movie.h264 /mnt/usb/movie.mp4`

`libcamera-jpeg -o /mnt/usb/still.jpg`

Again, the video works but the stills not and again, both work when executing via the cmd. What am I doing wrong?

Cheers, Bert